# DataGridView.Sorted how to tell which column was sorted?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

DataGridView.Sorted fires when a user clicks on the header to sort the grid. How can I tell programmatically which column header was clicked? And/or which column was sorted?

I tired the code below but the Sorted event fires before the click event. Doevents in either sub  didn't help.

I can move the call to GreenBar to the click event but that seems like a bad idea as it depends on the firing order anomaly.

> ```
> Private Sub dgvMAFTrans_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvMAFTrans.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
>     msLastMAFHeaderClicked = dgvMAFTrans.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
> End Sub
> ```

```
Private Sub dgvMAFTrans_Sorted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvMAFTrans.Sorted
    Application.DoEvents()
    GreenBar(dgvMAFTrans, msLastMAFHeaderClicked)
End Sub
```

Code to add a green bar affect:

```
Sub GreenBar(dgvRef As DataGridView, ColumnName As String)
    Dim sLastTrans As String = ""
    Dim bAddColor As Boolean = False
    If dgvRef.RowCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Try
        sLastTrans = dgvRef.Rows(0).Cells(ColumnName).Value
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub ' no transid
    End Try
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvRef.Rows
        If row.Cells(ColumnName).Value <> sLastTrans Then
            bAddColor = Not bAddColor
            sLastTrans = row.Cells(ColumnName).Value
        End If
        If bAddColor Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `DataGridView`'s [`SortedColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortedcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to see which column was sorted.

Another usefull property is the [`SortOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Unfortunately Get only SortedColumn is Nothing when the gird is fist loaded so it isn't a perfect solution, but it does worked for user sorting after the first display.

Comment: The value of the property is set by either the user clicking a column header to sort (if that is enabled) or by you calling sort on the data grid view manually. By default it assumes the rows are unordered. If they are ordered when you populate it you may want to call the [DataGridView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) yourself to ensure that it is set (which also ensures the sort arrow glyphs are set properly on the column.